# how install pdo-mysql in centos7

Tags: pdo, laravel-5, centos7

I install laravel 5 and then install packages neede.

I install php-pdo and some other but now i cant install pdo-mysql and laravel return error.

```
PDOException in PDOConnection.php line 47: could not find driver
```

I am use Centos 7 and PHP 5-6-29.

Answer (score 8):

Check which package is installed (which provider) and provides the stack, then use the same namespace.

- **Webtatic** uses php56w-*
- **IUS** uses php56u-*
- **remi-safe** (SCL packages) use php56-php-*
- **remi-php56** simply use php-*
- other providers can use something else

As you need [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/pdo_mysql) driver, simply

```
yum install <namespace>-pdo_mysql
```

(using the ext name, yum will find the correct package name which provides this ext).

Also check you don't have any "**exclude**" lines in the yum configuration (such as the ones provided in altered **cpanel** distributions)

Answer (score 4):

You can search package like

```
yum search php
```

Pick the ones you need and install them like this:

`yum -y install php-mysqlnd php-pdo`

In the next step I will install some common PHP modules that are required by CMS Systems like Wordpress, Joomla, and Drupal:

`yum -y install php-gd php-ldap php-odbc php-pear php-xml php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-soap curl curl-devel`

Answer (score 4):

Try using this

```
yum install php-mysql
systemctl restart httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/

I believe the driver is php56w-mysql so `yum install php56w-mysql` should do the job.

Comment: yum install php56w-mysql

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

base: fr.mirror.babylon.network
epel: epel.mirrors.ovh.net
extras: fr.mirror.babylon.network
ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
remi-safe: fr.mirror.babylon.network
updates: fr.mirror.babylon.network
webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
No package php56w-mysql available.

Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Have you added the repositories for your CentOS version ? As stated at the top of the link? You can try `yum search php | grep mysql` and see if you got anything similar?